# Did the Romans derive verbs from names?

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, names, derivation

I know the Romans did derive verbs from nouns (*laudare*, *finire*, *lucere*…), but did they ever derive verbs from names?
The Greeks did, for example forming *homerizein* (ὁμηρίζειν) from *Homeros*.

My understanding is that *-izare*, borrowed from Greek, was used (productively) in classical Latin.
However, I have never seen it attached to a name in classical context.

For example, the verb *latinizare* is easy to understand, but would a word like this ever have been used by classical authors?
(There are of course longer ways around this word, like *ad linguam Latinam adaptare*.)
I would prefer answers from the Augustan era or earlier, but later ones are also interesting.

Comment: I seem to remember an example from Cicero, where he uses a personal name turned into a verb. But I don't remember anything else, sorry.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have another entry for this exhibit that answers your question with a resounding *yes*.

Enter Plautus, in the [Menaechmi](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/plautus/menaechmi.shtml), with **three** verbs derived from proper names in his prologue:

> Atque hoc poetae faciunt in comoediis:
>   omnis res gestas esse Athenis autumant,
>   quo illud vobis graecum videatur magis;
>   ego nusquam dicam nisi ubi factum dicitur.
>   atque adeo hoc argumentum **graecissat**, tamen
>   non **atticissat**, verum **sicilicissitat**.

The *-isso* ending seems to be a Latinized (how meta of me!) version of the Greek *-ιζω* (*-izō*).

The meaning of these verbs was not immediately apparent to me, so I defer to the authority of [Henry Thomas Riley's translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0101%3Aact%3Dprologue%3Ascene%3D0#note3). Note that he inverts the order of the above two sentences:

> And, in fact, **this subject is a Greek one; still, it is not an Attic, but a Sicilian one**. But in their Comedies the poets do this; they feign that all the business takes place at Athens, in order that it may appear the more Grecian to you. I will not tell you that this matter happened anywhere except where it is said to have happened.

He adds in a footnote the following:

> *Graecissat, Atticissat, Sicelissat*: Perhaps these words might be more literally translated, "Graecize," "Atticize," and "Sicilicize."

Just imagine how wonderful life would be if words like "Sicilicize" were more frequently used!

Comment: So then rather than *Latinificare* or *Latinizare* we'd have *Latinissare*?

Comment: My experience is that Plautus reflects spoken patterns and often diverges from standard orthography: if you're writing  in good ol' Ciceronian style, I'd recommend using -izo while knowing that such words were probably spoken by the masses as -isso. Just a conjecture, though.

Comment: I imagine the -dz sound of a Greek zeta would be difficult for someone who never uses that sound otherwise

Answer (score 8):

I don’t know how far you want to stretch your definition of classical Latin, but Christianizo is used by Tertullian, and Judaizo in the Vulgata.

Comment: Thanks! This is a bit of a stretch for me, but still worth recording here. I (apparently correctly) assumed such a construction would appear in Christian Latin, but I was much less sure about Augustan or earlier language.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they did.

Cicero derived the verb [sullaturio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=sullaturio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) "to imitate or play the part of Sulla" from the name of the famous antique dictator Sulla.

Answer (score 3):

Proving non-existence is difficult, but in my (albeit limited) experience I've never seen *-izō* used in Classical Latin. The first verb-forming suffix that comes to mind is *-ficō*, derived from *fāciō*, applied to an adjective; the ancestor of English -ify. *Latinificāre* sounds a bit better than *Latinizāre* (which feels too Greek to me).

Comment: Have you seen PHI's concordance?  [Proving non-existence](http://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=izo%23) is (sort of) possible.

Comment: Thank you! *Latinificare* indeed sounds more Latin than *latinizare*. But do you know if the Romans ever attached *-ficare* to names? The name need not be *Latium* or the adjective *Latinus* derived from it.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta and Draconis: rather that guessing you could use the "words ending with" option on Perseus.

Comment: @Nathaniel: Thanks for the link to the PHI on the Web, really appreciated!