# Is the suffix -izo, -izare, -izavi, -izatum formal?

Tags: derivation, suffixes, vulgar-latin

The suffix -ize (or similar) are used to form verbs from nouns and adjectives in several Romance languages.

Wiktionary suggests that this stems from the vulgar latin -izo, -izare, -izavi, -izatum, which (ultimately) is borrowed from Ancient Greek.

It seems to me that there are no Latin literature which use this suffix. Even the Vicipaedia page for [factorisation](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_factores_resolutio) is "In factores resolutio".

Is it proper usage to append this suffix to words in Latin?

Comment: See https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/745/did-the-romans-derive-verbs-from-names/776#776 for a few early examples, which romanized zeta as -ss-