# Did the Romans create any irregular verbs?

Tags: verbs, derivation, conjugation

Most newly-formed Latin verbs were put into the nice, regular first conjugation: both deriving from existing words (*dīcō, -ere* > *dīctō, -āre*) and with borrowings (*[Graecissō, -āre](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/776/406)*).

English is mostly the same, with verbs like *google, googled, googled* and *xerox, xeroxed, xeroxed* falling into the "weak conjugation". But occasionally, existing words will fall into the rare, mostly-closed "strong conjugation": *dive, dove, dived*. And even more rarely, newly-coined verbs will end up in the "strong conjugation": *yeet, yote, yoten*.

Did this ever happen in Latin? That is, did a Latin word ever shift from the first conjugation into a different one, or was a newly-coined verb put into one of the other conjugations?

Comment: Is *yote* as a past tense of *yeet* real (say beyond the occasional joke)? The form I see over and over again is *yeeted*.

Comment: @cmw I've heard it frequently; in a joking context, true, but that's the pragmatics of _yeet_ in general.

Comment: I am sure that neither google nor xeror are verbs by the same reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example of derivation pushing first conjugation verbs to the third conjugation is given by prefixed versions of *dare*.
The short *a* is weakened and one ends up with verbs like *addere* which behave according to the third conjugation.

A second example arises in derivation of verbs from adjectives.
You can derive *ruber > rubere* and *albus > albere* and many others.
These second conjugation verbs describe state rather than action.

If you are willing to stretch the definition of "newly-coined verb", one example is adding prefixes to just about any verb and another one is deriving new verbs from *facere/fieri* by adding something like *cale-*.

Comment: BTW some of what look like prefixed versions of *dare* are probably not from the root of *dare*, but from that of *facio* -- according to de Vaan this is the case for *addere*. But your point holds for other verbs.

Comment: @TKR That is surprising; *facere* and *dare* seem to be pretty far from each other phonetically and the perfect and participle stems do match *dare* quite well. What would be a safe prefixed version of *dare* then? *Dedere*?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: I believe there are two Latin stems with d-, one from a Proto-Indo-European root meaning "give", the other from a root meaning "put, make" or similar. I think the Proto-Indo-European of the latter was something like *dʰe-, also present in Greek tithêmi (root the-) and Latin facio. I forgot when Proto-Indo-European *dʰ turns into d in Latin, and when into f.

Comment: @Cerberus If I remember right, all the "voiced aspirates" become `/f/` initially, and become normal voiced consonants medially? Something like that. It's why we have _futūrus_ with `/f/` but _amābō_ with `/b/`, both from `*bʰ`.

Comment: That's pretty much right. *Facere* < \*dʰeh₁-, *dare* < \*deh₃-. Medial \*dʰ becomes Latin *d*, so prefixed *-dere* could come from either.

Comment: @Draconis and TKR: noted!

Answer (score 2):

The [inchoative verbs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchoativ#Latein) in *-scere* like *rubescere, rubesco, rubui* were a productive class forming new verbs that aren't in the 1st conjugation, but in the third; and while being quite consistent they have the additional quirk that the *-sc-* infix is only present in the present stem, but absent is the perfect stem.